# Trying to understand the magic the author of this PDF did explaining the critically damped equation

Tags: passive-networks, resonance, damping-factor, equation

I am reading [this doc](http://tuttle.merc.iastate.edu/ee201/topics/capacitors_inductors/RLC_transients.pdf) about the equations for the step function for the RLC circuit, critically damped solution.

At page 16 we have these lines...

[image]

But there is a magic between these lines...

[image]

How the first line became the second one?

Comment: How not??? Are you familiar with the product rule?

Comment: The constant "B" is an integration constant.

Comment: I think it may be time to switch authors for reading materials haha :) I feel like _nearly all of your questions_ in the last two months have been about why this author decided to skip out important steps to the problem.

Comment: @KingDuken - I have tried many, all of them do some magic at some point without explaining. I like to understand everything. Simply accepting some step would be like puzzle missing a piece.

Comment: @jonk - Yes I am but it is not that obvious to guess the product rule in reverse when you are not expecting it.

Comment: Sounds true. I remember my physics professor back in college was teaching us about some electromagnetics and he literally wrote an equation and he completely skipped some Stoke's Theorem and all of us were entirely confused. Well on the bright side, you're almost done reading this document haha.

Comment: @KingDuken - be aware that I can ask for more help to understand all the magic these guys do... 

Comment: It's far more instructive to research it yourself - 'independent learning'. Having everything laid on a plate does nothing to challenge and develop the intellect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply the product rule in reverse:

$$\frac{d}{dt}[e^{\alpha t}v_{tr}] = e^{\alpha t}\frac{dv_{tr}}{dt} + v_{tr}\frac{d}{dt}[e^{\alpha t}]
=e^{\alpha t}\frac{dv_{tr}}{dt} + \alpha e^{\alpha t} v_{tr}$$

Comment: WOWWWWWWWWWWWWW! Brilliant. I was suspecting something on that direction but would never guess exactly that. THANKS!